# How to generate t-value, F-value or Chi-square in the summary table using R package "gtsummary"?

Tags: gtsummary

I am working on creating summary table using the excellent R package "gtsummary", it really help me a lot in efficiently and accurately generating summary tables. But I wonder whether some of the statistics such as t-value, F-value, and Chi-square could be automatically generated just like the p-value?

```
library(gtsummary)

add_p_ex1 <-
  trial[c("age", "grade", "response", "trt")] %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p()
```

[Here is the summary table generated using "gtsummary"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fghOV.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATED 2021-07-23

The test statistics are returned in a column called `statistic`. The column, however, is hidden by default from the output. You can add the test statistics to the table by assigning a column header (which will auto unhide the column). Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.2'

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p(test = all_continuous() ~ "t.test") %>%
  # add a header to the statistic column, which is hidden by default
  # adding the header will also unhide the column
  modify_header(statistic ~ "**Test Statistic**") %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(statistic ~ style_sigfig)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Professor Sjoberg, thank you very much for the detail replay.  The answer  help me a lot.

Comment: Professor Sjoberg, I have work out the t-value and chi-square in the summary table follow your valuable advice. Now when I move on, I came up with another puzzle with the "digits setting" in the summary table, as bellow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61638996/why-the-function-round-does-not-work-on-the-digits-of-p-value-and-how-to-adju

Answer (score 0):

modify_fmt_fun(statistic ~ style_sigfig)
this part of the code doesn't work. however the rest gives the output with 4 d